# Why is Date showing up as a String in Rest API Response

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, postman

Recently I ran into this situation:
my Rest API controller is returning this myResponse of type MyResponse:

```
public class MyResponse{
     private List<Stuff> stuffs; 
}

public class Stuff{
     private Date date; 
}

public class myController{
    ResponseEntity<MyResponse> result = ResponseEntity.ok().body(myService.getResp(myRequest));
    return result; 
}
```

and when I run debugger and put breakpoint on "return result" in controller, the date value inside result is of still Date type: "Mon Jan 10 00:00:00 CST 2022".

But somehow in Postman it's showing "2022-02-10" instead:

{"stuffs" : [{"date": "2022-01-10"}]}

What is the reason for this? where did it change?

Comment: SpringBoot has a configured JSON marshaller for Response objects that configures Date types

Comment: A Date is always a Striing in JSON, it's just not formatted the way you want.
How you change the default settings depends on a few things, too long for a comment. See the explanation at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-formatting-json-dates